# jquery validate checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have a form as follows Instead of pressing the submit button and the message Form successful submitted comes, the message is no longer displayed and the user goes to another url.
Like an approval of the first rules of the website

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
      alert("Form successful submitted!");
    }
  });
  
  $('#quickForm').validate({
    rules: {
      terms: {
        required: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      terms: "  please tick cheakbax"
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form role="form" id="quickForm" action="http://google.ca">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck1"></label>   ok! thanks.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">open website</button></center>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code you've shown works fine, as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. The behaviour you describe, where the jQuery validate library fails to stop the standard form submission, normally occurs when there's an error in your validation logic and the form submission is not cancelled. Check the console for errors when you submit the form - don't forget to check the 'preserve log' option though, otherwise the console will be cleared when a new page loads.

Comment: Rory McCrossan hello Thanks, but I want the user to enter another user page by confirming the checkbox. If you can help, repair the above code snippet for me.

Comment: your code has a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

```js
  

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
      alert("Form successful submitted!");
    }
  });
  
  $('#quickForm').validate({
    rules: {
      terms: {
        required: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      terms: "  please tick cheakbax"
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="quickForm" action="http://google.ca">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="custom-control-input" id="exampleCheck1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="exampleCheck1"></label>   ok! thanks.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">open website</button></center>
  </div>
</form>
```